# How to iterate over case insensitive sorted dictionary items?

Tags: python

Example:

```
>>> d = {'answer':1, 'Question':2}
>>> for i, j in sorted(d.items()): print i
Question
answer
```

I would like case insensitive list:

```
answer
Question
```

and I believe it can be done in simple Pythonic way.

Comment: Below snippets does not work for Cyrillic words (UTF-8 encoded). In this case `.lower()` does not work so I took a freedom to extend this question. If no answer is provided I'll select below answered question by `jellybean`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's just about printing the keys:

```
for i in sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda x: x.lower()): print i
```

If you need the values afterwards, you could do

```
for i, j in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0].lower()): print i, j
```

EDIT: Even shorter and better (since you have d in scope):

```
for i in sorted(d, key=str.lower):
    print i, d[i]
```

Comment: sorry, I added comment below question

Comment: @zetah: To sort utf-8 encoded keys, convert them to unicode first: `sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: x[0].decode('utf-8').lower())`.

Comment: Oh man I hate so much doing Python in anything than ASCII. I'm trying to make my own `lower` function like `def clower(word, r):\n word = r[word[0]] + word[1:]\n return word` where r is dict mapping with replacements, but I'm helpless with encode/decode errors. You snippet does no good also, i.e. `x = 'Питон'` OR `x = u'Питон'.encode('utf-8')` OR `x = r'Питон'` all return `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: unexpected end of data` on `x[0].decode('utf-8')`. I just can't wait Python 3 become main distribution

Answer (score 3):

```
import string
sorted(d.items(), key=string.lower)
```

Comment: It doesn't work to me.
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: As per other comments, it should be `sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0].lower())`

Answer (score 2):

```
for k in sorted(d, key=lambda k: k.lower()):
    print k
```